# How do you invert search criteria in sonarqube 4.5?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am trying to scan through the existing issues in my project.  Most of the issues belong to one or two rules.  Is there a way to add "not including rule ID" to search queries?

Comment: First, no there's not. Also, "Most of the issues belong to one or two rules"...? Each issue belongs to one and only one rule.

Comment: I meant most of the backlog is caused by one or two rules.  I have not tuned the ruleset yet.